# Non-intractable view

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I make a view non-intractable.
I have two canvas views stacked upon each other in a frame layout.
Both canvas takes whole screen area and both are transparent.
I want to show some PNG on the upper canvas, and let user draw on the lower canvas.

Problem is when user touches the screen, touch input is taken by upper canvas and since it does nothing (drawing in on the lower canvas), nothing happens.

I want the upper canvas to act just as an overlay view with no interactions and no events assigned, all of these should be consumed by lower view. If I set the upper overlay to invisible I can draw on lower canvas(as now lower canvas is receiving all the inputs).

Also canvas is not a standard canvas, but a custom one. It's derived directly from View class.
But I think a derived view wouldn't cause problem. I just don't know how to proceed.

I tried using onTouch() on upper canvas and call onTouch() of lower canvas, did't worked.
I am testing some other things like dispatchTouch() on 2 Buttons, but nothing seem certain to me. Help would be really appreciated.

Edit: Added XML Layout code

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.samsung.sdraw.CanvasView 
        android:id="@+id/canvas1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="cnvs1Click"
        android:text="Canvas1" />

    <com.samsung.sdraw.CanvasView 
        android:id="@+id/canvas2" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Canvas2" 
        android:onClick="cnvs2Click"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

But I still think problem would be solved by View(s).
Canvas is from [S pen SDK](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=10644)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a special case, haven't played to see if this is true, but normally in your onTouch events etc you just return false if you haven't handled the event, and the event bubbles up through each view's touch events until something returns true, which indicates it's handled hit.

if you make your one view (the upper layer) just return false from it's onTouch, the lower views onTouch should receive the event.

Comment: Would you help elaborating that one, on how to use that. I mean when I add onTouchEvent() eclipse autogenerates method returning false, but still then I am able to draw on upper canvas, which is not what I want.

Comment: If you'll edit your initial question to give an example piece of code and an example layout, then I'll happily have a play and try to help

Comment: I can surely post example code. The canvas is actually is a custom canvas as I explained in question. It is actually a special canvas supplied with Samsung Galaxy S pen SDK. You need to have the sdk too. It's a small sdk [S pen sdk link](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=10644&nacode=uk) .

Comment: Just Touching on the Canvas (provided with sdk) starts drawing. I initally didn't tell it was S pen sdk cause, last time I asked a question relating to that and didn't got a single reply :(

Comment: okay, custom sdk, no problem, we can work with that.

have you tried, on the canvas you DON'T want to touch, calling setDrawable(false) ?

Comment: yeah, it makes canvas not to draw anything, but still takes touch inputs. I actually used that technique to pan the canvas.

Comment: okay, does the upper canvas actually have to be this custom pen canvas then?  you just want to display a png on it right? you're not doing anything else with it, or wanting it to respond to anything, then i'd suggest stop using this custom canvas and just use a normal android one?

Comment: Yes, it should be canvas. But what I can do save the image drawn on that canvas and will remove (or hide) that canvas. Then I can show the Image on an ImageView, but then image view will take touch inputs, and lower canvas will again be deprived. If you can guide me from here that would be great. I am willing to use normal Android Views

Answer (score 0):

try in the XML to add to the root view

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: Do you mean to add these values to frameLayout (which contains these canvas views).